# Отдача файлов php скриптом

Tags: php

Нужно отдавать файлы пользователям на скачивание не светя при этом прямой путь.

Сейчас все работает таким образом:

```
<?
$urll = $arResult["arUser"]["LOGIN"];
    $utllx = $urll . ".xlsx";
?>
<a href='<?echo $utllx?>'>Скачать excel файл</a>
```

Но так видно путь к файлу. Подскажите пожалуйста, как скрыть путь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$name = './img/ok.png';
$fp = fopen($name, 'rb');

// отправляем нужные заголовки
header("Content-Type: image/png");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($name));

// скидываем картинку и останавливаем выполнение скрипта
fpassthru($fp);
exit;
```

Ссылка на мануал, пример оттуда же
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fpassthru.php

Еще полезные заголовки : `Content-Disposition`, `Content-Length`

Как правило, при таком подходе создается временная ссылка на файл, сохраняется в БД. Ссылка состоит из хеша и пути файла. Хеш показываем пользователю, путь не показываем. Как только пользователь скачал файл - помечаем ссылку использованной или просто удаляем из БД.

Comment: Сделал. На страничку вываливает огромную кучу чего-то типо PK!��ˣ�[Content_Types].xml �(��U�N�0�#��

Comment: А еще лучше использовать XSendFile для Apache или X-Accel-Redirect для nginx. Советую почитать про эти варианты. PHP не участвует непосредственно в передаче файла, что снижает нагрузку на сервер и позволяет отдавать файлы любого размера.

Comment: `header("Content-Type: image/png");` остался? для `xml` это должно быть `header("Content-Type: text/xml");`

Comment: @ilyaplot , за X-Accel-Redirect отдельное спасибо.